# How to make custom id as firebase default id

Tags: excel, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a POS app where I stored my inventory in firebase. The way I store it is that I first make an excel sheet given below
[image]

I convert this xls file to Json and then import it into firebase
It is stored like this in firebase

[image]

I want the firebase id to be my barcode id(eg:8901063142039) instead of 0 1 and 2 so that I can search it later using id.

So how should I fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to change the ids manually or

When you get the snapshot of all the documents, you can Query for the document with your `id`.

Answer (score 0):

While storing data to firebase, instead of using arraylist of product, use Map in which key is the id of the product and value the product details.

Comment: So how to do that in excel file because I upload the excel file and not from flutter code.

Comment: proper way is while uploading the data in formatted way, by writing a script in node or pythong or any other language you are comfortable, and uploading the data to firebase, check the link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data . else if it's just for learning purpose, may be u can read data in your flutter project and converting the data to required format (to the map) and uploading it under new node

Answer (score 0):

Since your JSON comes from such a structured data source, converting it is fairly straightforward with a script like this:

```js
let inventory = [{
  id: "someid",
  name: "somename",
  price: "20",
  qty: "1pc"
}, {
  id: "anotherid",
  name: "anothername",
  price: "20",
  qty: "1pc"
}]


let output = {};
inventory.forEach((o) => {
  output[o.id] = { name: o.name, price: o.price, qty: o.qty };
});

console.log(output);
```